# how to implement second level authentication in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a `devise` `authentication` already setup in my `application`.Now i want to implement `second level authentication` in `rails`. i want to `hard code` the `email` and `password` in coding in `controllers`. i want to compare this `email` and `password` with the `email` and `password` provided by the `user`. rather than saving in `database` and picking for `second level authentication`.,Because these 5 to 6 `links` are going to be used by only one `person` in the `company` at any point of time. i want to implement this for a 5 to 6 `actions` in my application in controller. how can i implement this? i checked a gem gem 'devise-authy' but it seems it sends a `password` to mobile for `otp` authentication. i dont want otp authentication. i want a second level authentication with the same email as devise email but the password should be different from the devise original password.(like in devise table i want to take one more column second_level_password.) is there any `gem` for this kind of requirement or is this `manually` coded. if it is `manually` coded then how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use before_action in rails controller.

Add following line of code in your controller.

```
before_action :second_level_access

private

def second_level_access
  #You can use your logic to get password
  unless current_user.second_level_password == params[:second_level_password]
   # signout to user because user is already logged in with devise.
   redirect_to session_path
  end
end
```

> EDIT

You can use

> attr_accessor_with_default :second_level_logged_in, false

add following line to `application controller`:

```
before_action :logged_in_with_second_level, if: 'current_user and !second_level_logged_in'

def logged_in_with_second_level
  redirect_to 'second_level_logged_in_form_page'
end
```

in `create action` of `second_level_logged_in`

add code `current_user.second_level_logged_in=true`

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. but upon clicking these links if the user not already logged in with the second_level_password then i want to provide the second_level_authentication form same as devise. If he already logged in with the second password no second level form will come. if he logout from the second level i want to logout only second level authentication with the first level authentication or session should remain same. how can i do this?

Comment: You can use attr_accessor_with_default :second_level_logged_in, false

add following line to application controller:
before_action :logged_in_with_second_level, if: 'current_user and !second_level_logged_in'

def logged_in_with_second_level
  redirect_to 'second_level_logged_in_form_page'
end  

in create action of second_level_logged_in
assign current_user.second_level_logged_in=true

Comment: @John,

I updated code in my answer, please have a look

Comment: Thanks. i will try it